# How do the radian have a unit?

Tags: units, rotation, dimensional-analysis, si-units

The radian is defined as the ratio of the circumference and the radius. Both are measured in meters. So there should not be a unit for that. But we use 'rad' as the unit of the radian value.

The coefficient of static/kinetic friction also the same, it is a ratio of both forces. Therefore it doesn't have a unit.

So, is there a special reason to have a unit for the radian value?

Comment: Duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193684/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are angles dimensionless and quantities such as length not?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193684/)

Answer (score 2):

Probably just to emphasise that you are not using degrees.  If we had never used degrees then we might not feel the need to say radians.

There are other unnecessary units e.g. becquerel and hertz.

Comment: The [radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) has a very precise and well defined meaning in mathematics.  It's a lot more than a label.  Degrees are simply a human convenience and we've used [many different units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_unit) for human purposes (e.g. a gradian) but none work in the same fundamental way that radians do for mathematics.

Comment: I recently had an interesting discussion about *Hertz*.   A document used *Hz* for frequency and *rad/s* for angular frequency.  After some thought, we all kind-of agreed that using *Hz* for angular frequency (without a clear statement that it *is* angular frequency) is not a good idea.  *Hz* is too strongly associated with frequency in our general opinion.

Comment: @StephenG No disagreement on the importance of radians in mathematics but the OP has a point.  It doesn't need a unit in the way that velocity or area do.  If we had not got into the habit of using degrees before realising that maths worked better in radians, we might not have felt the need fid the name.  We would just say that the angle was $\frac{\pi}{2}$.