# Units of angular speed vs linear speed

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, rotation, angular-velocity, si-units

I'm studying pendulums, and the units have me a bit confused.

In a pendulum, Iw^2=mgL.

Putting together the units of the left side of the equation, we get gm^2 (rads^-1)^2=g(m^2)(s^-2)(rad^2).

But the units of the right side of the equation equal g(m^2)(s^-2)

Where does the unit radian fit in? How do I deal with the unit radian when dealing with measures of linear speed?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/351543/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The radian unit should not be written. It is just a name for a unit-less measure. For example, *radians-per-seconds* should be written $\mathrm{[s^{-1}]}$. [The radian unit](https://www.allthatmatters.academy/lessons/the-radian-unit/) is defined as how many radius-lengths along the periphery an angle corresponds to. It is *periphery-length-per-radius*, meaning *metres-per-metres*, and therefore unit-less.