# What are the units of wavenumber? With or without radians?

Tags: waves, definition, dimensional-analysis, wavelength, si-units

Sometimes, I see that [wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) units are $\text{m}^{-1}$, but on the other hand, (and by definition of $k = \omega/v = 2\pi/\lambda$), it is $\text{rad/m}$. What is correct?

Comment: Wavenumber has units of inverse length.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan Ok, but why? From k=ω/v=2π/λ it is rad/m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Both are correct](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Commutative_diagram_of_harmonic_wave_properties.svg/800px-Commutative_diagram_of_harmonic_wave_properties.svg.png). It's just an issue of angular versus linear units. The linear wavenumber $\tilde{v}$ is
$$\tilde{v}=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$
while the angular wavenumber $k$ is
$$k=2\pi\tilde{v}=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$
The linear wavenumber is seldom used compared to the angular wavenumber, so most of the time, by "wavenumber", we mean the angular one $k$. Remember that the whole issue of angular and linear arises because
$$1 \;\text{cycle} = 2\pi \;\text{radians}$$
As for the radian itself, it is a dimensionless quantity because it is defined as the ratio of lengths. For more information, see [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252288) and [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193684).

Answer (score 0):

[Radians are dimensionless](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) as they are the ratio of an arclength (which has units of length) to the radius (also units of length).