# Dimension of angular directions in a metric?

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, dimensional-analysis

I am conceptually confused about the dimensions of the angular directions in a metric tensor.

For instance, consider
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = \frac{1}{x^2}(-dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2 d \theta^2)
\end{equation}
I never see the angular components, here $d\theta^2$, not accompanied by a length squared term. The RHS, $ds^2$, is length squared. Same goes for $dr^2$ and $dt^2$ (in natural units of course). But $r^2 d \theta^2$ should to me be length squared and angle squared? Are the angular directions dimensionless? I am confused...

Comment: [Angles are dimensionless](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193684/)

Comment: Thank you @JohnRennie