# What is the dimension of $2^{4 \text{ Newton}}$?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

If you have a number with a dimensional quantity in its exponent, what is the dimensionality of this number then? For example when you have $e^{(4J)}$ or $2^{(4N)}$, with $J$ and $N$ respectively Joules and Newton.

I know that you can't take the logarithm of a dimensional quantity, but I don't really understand the case with exponents.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13060/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7668/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48019/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109995/2451, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/364771/2451 and links therein.

Comment: A very simple way to see that the argument of an exponential *must* be dimensionless: the Taylor expansion $e^x=1+x+o(x)$. You can see that 1 and x must have the same dimension (hence, none).

Comment: @Miyase [A more complete writing of the expansion avoids that particular problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/7673/146039).

Comment: *If you have a number with a dimensional quantity in its exponent* This simply indicates that you made a mistake somewhere. Or there were other factors that make it dimensionless and you didn’t combine them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $\mathcal e^C \in \mathbb R$ to be valid, $C$ itself must belong to the real set. However, it does not, because it's a measurement unit (type) . Hence initial proposition is invalid.

In general, all mathematical mappings in some sets $\mathbb R, \mathbb C$ which expects input to be a number and returns element in the same set, - does not work with dimensions, because it's a type. So, $x^C, e^C, \ln(C), \sin(C) $ and similar does not lead to a number, but rather to a new type, which is ill-defined in physics, because has no analog in measurements.

However, other type mappings like $\sqrt[n]{C} $ may be valid, as for example $\sqrt[3]{m^3} = m$ (length) which has analog in measurements and real world.

So, the final thought is that for dimensional mapping $C_1 \to C_2$ to be valid, - both units $C_1, C_2$ must have physical analog in the real world, otherwise we will end up with dimensions which simply doesn't make any sense.

**BONUS**

Why do math operations like $+-\times /$ work on non-numbers, dimensions ?

Examples:

*Addition*

We can make addition like $4J+2J$, because it reassembles equation of the form $aC+bC$ and by distributive property of binary operations we can re-write it to be $(a+b)C$, which leaves us adding plain real numbers and scaling the result by a measurement unit $C$.

*Division*

$\frac {4J}{2J}$ makes sense only because it makes form $\frac {aC}{bC}$, which is equivalent to $\frac ab$, so just a division of plain real numbers  and result is dimensionless, because dimensions cancel-out.

*Subtraction*

Validity is same as for addition because $aC-bC = aC+(-b)C$

*Multiplication*

And pity, here dimensional magic ends, because $aC \times bC = (a \times b) C^2$ does not guarantee by itself that **new** dimension $C^2$ is physically valid, i.e. we get an element which does not apply to an old set and thus must be validated separately. So, $4J \cdot 2J = 8J^2$ does not make sense, but $4m \cdot 2m = 8m^2$ - does, because it's an area.

Comment: So if you should attribute a dimension to $e^{4J}$, it would be $e^J$? But since that isn't a dimension of a measurable quantity, that is kind of meaningless?

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent to $\left (e^4\right) ^J$. $e^4$ part is calculable, but dimension $x^J$ has no physical correspondence to a measurements.

Comment: Joules-squared makes sense and is a perfectly valid unit. It even occurs in a famous formula, but that’s irrelevant; no combination of units is “physically invalid”.

Comment: @Ghoster, So you say that unit $e^J$ makes sense to you? Ok, can you share more info what this unit represents? And formulas doesn't validate types, experiments and measurements do. I can make artificially thousands of meaningless types, like $\sin(kg)$ and can even create formula for you using that type, like $m=\sin^{-1} ( \sin(m)) $, but it will be meaningless mumbo-jumbo, no?

Comment: No, I do *not* say that. I wasn’t talking about $e^J$, which is dimensionally inconsistent. I was talking about $J^2$, $J^{19/3}s^{7/8}$, etc., which have no inconsistency, make sense, and are valid. Your statement that $J^2$ does not make sense but $m^2$ does is simply wrong.

Comment: You said that "no combination of units is physically invalid." And $e^J$ is basically a "combined unit", so you did say that actually. Oh my, and what $J^{19/3} $ unit measures or let alone joule squared? Dimensional consistency is not everything, derived unit must have grounds also in measurements. I haven't heard anybody measuring $J^2$, but it's plenty of resources with **energy** measurement.

Comment: And I don't see $J^2$ in SI derived units- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit), so I stand by myself, - that $J^2$ is not very common thing in Physics. Btw, same for $(m/s)^2$, it's used in many places like kinetic energy, statistical physics and others, but by itself, only velocity makes sense. To make sense of $v^2$ you have to combine it with some addition unit, for getting derived SI unit from velocity. Like I said, there's infinite possibilities for mangling units, but only several have been used in Physics. Why? Think about it.

Comment: *Dimensional consistency is not everything, derived unit must have grounds also in measurements.* That is *completely* false, but I’m not going to argue with you further. I’ve downvoted and I’m done.

Comment: No need to be angry. If you can explain what $J^2$ means - do so, and I'll replace it in my post with other meaningless unit which must be plenty, like $kg^3$ or $s^e$. I understand that in theory you can do whatever you like with units, like  assign 1 to all units or use arbitrary unit system. However, Physics describes fundamental laws of nature, which doesn't have billions of independent parameters and so **real** unit system reflects that, - only couple base SI units and several derived units and it's enough for physics laws mapping.