# Units inside a logarithm

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis

I have troubles understanding a seemingly simple integral in a physical context. Take a look at $\int_{V_1}^{V_2} \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{V}$ which appears in isothermal expansions (V being the volume of a gas). Now of course the result is $\ln{V_2}-\ln{V_1}$ or using log laws $\ln{\frac{V_2}{V_1}}$.

The first expression would require you to evaluate the logarithm of a unit of volume which to my unterstanding is impossible. The second expression makes sense, though. How can you account for this apparent discrepancy?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109995/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Note that the integrand is dimensionless and so must be the limits.  That is to say, the limits are normalized (dimensionless) volumes.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Um, shouldn't the limits of integration match the units of the differential, not the whole integrand?

Comment: @ChrisWhite, for $f(V) = \ln(V)$, $V$ is dimensionless and $df(V) = \frac{1}{V}dV$ which *is* dimensionless.

Comment: Basically you *can't* do $\ln V_1 - \ln V_2$ if $V_i$ have units, but you *can* do $\ln (V_1 / v) - \ln (V_2 / v)$ where $v$ is an arbitrary unitful constant, so in practice you can always just cross out the units as long as they are both the same unit.

Answer (score 7):

> How can you account for this apparent discrepancy?

There is no discrepancy in the value of the *difference* of the logs 
$$
\log(V_1)-\log(V_2)
$$
and the value of the log of the *ratio*
$$
\log{V_1/V_2}\;.
$$
And neither of these depends on the choice of units. This is because, for both the difference and the ratio, the units cancel. For example, suppose I represent the "units" as a number "U" such that 
$$
V=\alpha U\;,
$$
where $\alpha$ is unitless.

Then
$$
\log(V_1)-\log(V_2)=\log(\alpha_1 U)-\log(\alpha_2 U)=\log(\alpha_1)+\log(U)-\log(\alpha_2)-\log(U)
$$
$$
=\log(\alpha_1)-\log(\alpha_2)\;.
$$

And, similarly,
$$
\log(V_1/V_2)=\log(\frac{\alpha_1 U}{\alpha_2 U})=\log(\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_2})\;.
$$

Not much else to say but that... Clearly, trying to interpret $\log(V_1)$ on its own doesn't make sense since changing the unit changes the numerical value... but the interpretation and sensibleness of the *difference* of the logs certainly makes sense and is independent of the choice of units.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I do understand that the ratio $\frac{V_1}{V_2}$ is dimensionless. What I don't quite understand is your rearrangement of the difference $\ln{V_1}-\ln{V_2}$. Why are you "allowed" to apply logarithmic identities to an expression including physical units? Does $\ln(U)$ even mean anything (where U is a unit as in your example)?

Comment: @df42 well, think about it like this: does $U$ even mean anything?

Comment: Nice answer. +1. This explanation works for subtraction only. Is there a similar way to show that units are "eliminated" for addition?

Comment: No, because they're not.

Comment: Note at the very start the units of the terms in the integral cancel $$dV/V$$

Answer (score 2):

If you introduce any unit $v$ in terms of which you express the numerical values of $V_1,V_2$, then you see

$\ln\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{V_2/v}{V_1/v}\right)=\ln\left(V_2/v\right)-\ln\left(V_1/v\right)$

So if $V_1$ and $V_2$ were the integral bounds of a single integral sign, it's only important that make sure you express the numerical value of $V_1,V_2$, in the difference of the two log-expressions, as multiples of the same arbitrary scale.

Writing $\ln\left(V_2\right)-\ln\left(V_1\right)$ implies you fixed a unit for them and it wasn't explicitly emphasised. People don't get in trouble here because the result is really independent of the unit, as it being equal to $\ln\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)$ demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics when we put a number x in ln x, we assume x belong to a field, so x must be a dimensionless number.
So it is possible to put a pure number of x in ln x.
However, many people seem not to know the following expression of lnx as an infinite series expansion.
In fact, lnx=2{(x-1)/(x+1)+(1/3)[(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)]/[(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)]+(1/5)[(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)(x-1)]/[(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)]+,,,,,,,} .
So now it is clear that we cannot put x in lnx if x has a dimension.

I have published these issues in the three papers:

1. Mayumi, K. and Giampietro, M. 2010. “Dimensions and Logarithmic Function: A Short Critical Analysis” , Ecological Economics,Vol.69, pp. 1604-1609;
2. Mayumi, K., and Giampietro, M. 2012. “Response to “Dimensions and logarithmic function in economics: A comment””, Ecological Economics Vol. 75, pp. 12-14;
3. Mayumi, K., Giampietro, M., And Ramos-Martin, J. 2012. “Reconsideration of Dimensions and Curve Fitting Practice in View of Georgescu-Roegen’s Epistemology in Economics”, 
   Romanian Journal of Economic Forecasting, Vol.15, No.4, pp.17-35.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Welcome to Physics! Please note that we do have an [equation editor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) built into the site, which can help improve readability of your post.