# What will be the dimension of $x$ in $e^x$?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units

I just want to know if in an exponential function $e^x$, will $x$ always be dimensionless? If so, Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exponential or logarithm of a dimensionful quantity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109995/). See also, for instance, [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13060), or [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167313) or [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/554241), etc.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot

Comment: Why should this question be reopened? As I show in my comment above, there is already a multitude of similar questions on this site. It is insane to continue adding new ones all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Maclaurin series for the exponential function

$$e^{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$

So to be able to sum this up you have to have $x$ dimensionless.

Comment: So whenever we have any exponential function,the dimensions of the power will always be dimensionless?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the "answer" would be dependent on specific units chosen for $x$, to say the least.