# Experimental methodology - what are the units?

Tags: experimental-physics

I have a problem with finding the units in my experiment. So I have come as far as creating a chart where the y-axis is logn* with the unit 10^27∙m^(-2)∙s^(-1) and the x-axis with logp (10^5∙Pa).

From the chart I got the equation y=1,008+22,437 and from that I got n*=(2,74∙10^22)∙ p^1,008 (n*=a∙p^b).

My problem is now what the units for a and b are, any help how I can think?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109995/exponential-or-logarithm-of-a-dimensionful-quantity, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018673/what-does-the-slope-of-a-log-log-plot-represent

Comment: You can format your post using [MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make it easier for others to read and answer. For this post in particular, it may also reduce clutter to not use your specific numbers since without content its impossible for anyone to tell what they mean anyhow.

Comment: You cannot take the log of a physical quantity with units,,, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238390/units-of-a-log-of-a-physical-quantity

Comment: @DJohnM I understand that but I'm looking for the units of a and b are they also unitless then?