# Why this constant is included in the tortoise coordinate?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, coordinate-systems

In the Schwarzschild spacetime, the tortoise coordinate $r_\ast$ is defined by the property that

$$\dfrac{dr_\ast}{dr}=\left(1-\dfrac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1}$$

Now, we cam integrate this. Multiply by $r$ on the numerator and denominator to get

$$r_\ast = \int \dfrac{1}{1-\frac{2M}{r}}dr=\int\dfrac{r}{r-2M}dr$$

Now integrate by parts with $u =r$ and $dv = dr/(r-2M)$ we get $du = dr$ and $v = \ln(r-2M)$. Then

$$r_\ast =r\ln(r-2M)-\int \ln(r-2M)dr$$

We integrate the last term to get

$$r_\ast = r\ln(r-2M)-(r-2M)\ln(r-2M)+(r-2M)+C$$

Reorganizing yields

$$r_\ast = r+2M\ln(r-2M)-2M+C$$

We can obviously choose $C$ to cancel the $2M$.

But anyway, virtually *all references*, shows a different $r_\ast$. The canonical one is

$$r_\ast = r+2M\ln \dfrac{r-2M}{2M}.$$

So one has one additional $2M$ on the denominator. This is equivalent of picking

$$C=2M-2M\ln 2M$$

Now why is that? It is clear to me that one *can* do that, after all the initial differential equation is still satisfied, but why everyone does it? What's the point with that $2M$ on the denominator inside the $\ln$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Physicists *really* don't like to put dimensional variables inside a function like $\ln$, $\sin$, or $\exp$.  By choosing $C = 2M - 2M \ln (2M)$, you can combine the logarithmic terms into the logarithm of the dimensionless ratio $(r-2M)/2M$.

Further details on why having "naked" dimensional variables inside a function like $\ln$ is a bad idea:

- [Exponential or logarithm of a dimensionful quantity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109995/exponential-or-logarithm-of-a-dimensionful-quantity/109999)
- [What is the logarithm of a kilometer? Is it a dimensionless number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13060/what-is-the-logarithm-of-a-kilometer-is-it-a-dimensionless-number)