# Is a vector and a unit vector dimensionless

Tags: vectors, dimensional-analysis

Lets say I have a position vector $\vec r$. Is it dimensionless or does it have a dimension of length i.e  $[L]$.

Also does the unit vector $\hat r$ have a dimension?

Comment: Related: [what-is-the-logarithm-of-a-kilometer-is-it-a-dimensionless-number](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13060/what-is-the-logarithm-of-a-kilometer-is-it-a-dimensionless-number). Same vein I mean :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vectors do have dimensions. Specifically, the dimension of a vector is (and always must be) the same as the dimension of its components. This also means that al the components of a vector must have the same dimension.

In your example, the position vector $\vec r$ does indeed have units of length.

The vector $\hat r$ is defined as $\hat r = \vec r / |\vec r|$. Since we know that both $\vec r$ and $|\vec r|$ have units of length, we can conclude that $\hat r$ has units $L / L = 1$. In other words, it is dimensionless.

Comment: So that would mean that the unit vector $\hat r$ too has dimensions of length?

Comment: @BinaryGeek see my edit

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does have the dimension $[L]$. You can, however, be more specific and assign a different length dimension to each component. So that the $x$ component has length dimension of $[L_x]$ and analogous for $y$ and $z$. These are called [direction dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Huntley.27s_extension:_directed_dimensions), and can be helpful in dimensional analysis.

Comment: So that would mean that the unit vector $\hat r$ too has dimensions of length?

Comment: No, $\hat r$ has no units, as it is defined as the vector $r$ divided by the magnitude of $r$, which themselves both have the same units and therefore cancel to give a dimensionless unit vector

Comment: @Joseph, thanks but I'm not the OP and that's basically what I said :)

Answer (score -2):

I think it should have dimensions. 
Suppose the question were "what is the unit vector of 10 Newtons force pointing due north?".
Then the answer is "1 Newton due north".

Comment: A unit vector is a vector which has a magnitude of exactly 1, the arithmetic unit multiplier.  It has no units.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @John I think it is an answer. The question is whether a vector has units, and this answer says it should. It may have quality issues, but it does answer the question.