# Unit vector in displacement

Tags: vectors, units, dimensional-analysis, geometry

When we use vectors in physics why does the unit vector (for displacement) equals magnitude of 1 or magnitude of 1m?

Comment: "Unit vector" is more of a math concept than a physics concept. Unit vectors are a special case of _[basis vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra))_, which are part of how we associate a _[coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system)_ with a _[vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space)_. In particular, the basis vectors of a _[Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)_ are unit vectors.

Comment: Duplicate [Is a vector and a unit vector dimensionless?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172829/104696)