# What does it mean for a unit vector to have a magnitude of 1?

Tags: vectors, units, dimensional-analysis, linear-algebra

Imagine a Cartesian coordinate system  whose origin is associated with two unit vectors, **ê** and **â**, in a 2D-space. Now, let **0.5 cm** be the unit of length in this  coordinate system.

The magnitude of a unit vector is, by definition, **1**; Does this mean that the magnitude of one of our unit vectors is **1**  unit of length? Or, in other words, does this mean that **$\left | â \right |$ = $\left | ê \right |$ = 0.5cm**?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/438491/206691 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172829/206691

Answer (score 5):

The basis vectors are dimensionless quantities with magnitude 1. You create dimensional vectors to represent positions, velocities, accelerations, forces, etc. by multiplying each basis vector by a dimensional scalar and then adding together. For example,

$$\mathbf{r}=(2\,\text{cm})\hat{\mathbf{e}}+(3\,\text{cm})\hat{\mathbf{a}}$$

In other words, the *components* of a vector carry its dimensions. That way, the same basis vectors can be used to represent all kinds of different vectorial physical quantities.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a unit of length to be equal to $0.5\,\rm cm$ which we can call $1\,\rm ash$.

Suppose you move $5\,\rm ash$ in the $\hat e$ direction.

The displacement is $5\,\rm ash\, \hat e$ which is  $2.5\,\rm cm\, \hat e$

This means that $|\hat e| =1$ irrespective of what you are describing and whatever the units that you are using.