# How do I decide dimensions of a logarithmic function?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

How do I decide the dimensions of a trigonometric quantity and a logarithmic quantity?

For example, what are the dimensions for:
$$\frac{C}{B} = \frac{D^2}{A} + \log \left(\frac{AC}{BD}\right)$$

Comment: $\log , \sin, \cos, e^x ,...$ don't have any dimensions, they are pure numbers, like $1$

Comment: Please use mathjax to format mathematical expressions. To learn more about mathjax, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13060/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Dimension of any mathematical function is, simply stated, 1 (or more appropriately $M^0L^0T^0$). Also their arguments are supposed to be dimensionless.

So,

$$
[\ln(x)] = M^0\ L^0\ T^0\ K^0\ A^0\ mol^0\ cd^0 = 1
$$
and
$$
[x] = M^0\ L^0\ T^0\ K^0\ A^0\ mol^0\ cd^0 = 1
$$

so in your question.
$$
\left[\frac{C}{B}\right] = \left[\frac{D^2}{A}\right] 
= \left[\log(...)\right] = 1
$$
and
anything inside must be dimensionless.
$$
\left[\frac{AC}{BD}\right] = 1
$$