# Do the trigonometric functions preserve units?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, si-units

I saw an exercise where you had to calculate the units of $C_i, i=1,2$ from an equation like this:

- $v^2=2\cdot C_1x$ and
- $x=C_1\cdot \cos(C_2\cdot t)$

where

- $x$ means *meters*,
- $t$ means seconds and
- $v$ means velocity.

For $C_1$ I got $C_1=m/s^2$. But coming to $C_2$ the cosinus irritates me somehow:

$$x=C_1 \cdot \cos(C_2 t)\Rightarrow m=m/s^2 \cdot \cos(C_2 s)\Rightarrow s^2 = \cos(C_2 s)$$

Does this mean, that $C_2$ must have the unit $s$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but answered by [Fundamental question about dimensional analysis](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7668/520). In short the argument to a trigonometric function must be dimensionless (or a pure angle if you're one of those strange people who like to work in degrees), so either a conversion has been elided or there is a mistake.

Comment: @dmckee: I see know where I made my mistake. Since the result of cos must be dimensionsless, $C_2$ must be $1/s$ and therefore $C_1$ must be $m$. The two equations do not correlate, as I assumed by mistake. Thanks for the link, helped a lot!

Comment: An easy way to understand why functions such as $\sin$, $\cos$ or $\exp$ must have dimensionless arguments is to note that they have non-trivial power series, e.g. $\exp(x) = 1 + x + x^2/2 + \dots$. Since it doesn't make sense to add two quantities with different units, e.g. $1m + 3m^2$, we know that $x$ must be dimensionless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trigonometric functions don't "preserve" units. The expression under a trigonometric function must be dimensionless and so is the value of a trigonometric function.

Thus, *C<sub>2</sub>* in your equations is in units of frequency: *Hz* or *1/s*.

There is an error in one of the equations, perhaps a missing constant.

Answer (score 0):

I know where you have done the mistake . I have solved this question earlier and thus in the second case we don't need to take the dimensions of C1 as obtained in our  first case . Now if you solve it as @Adam said the correct answer would be Hertz