# What does really mean by- power of a number or an exponential function is dimensionless?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

Is power of only a number or an exponential function is dimensionless? If power of any other thing can also be dimensionless then please explain with examples.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Polynomials_and_transcendental_functions

Comment: if i had understood that, i would have never posted this question. i want an answer which can easily be understood.@user80551

Comment: One way to think about it is this: Mathematical identities for functions like the exponential function are about *numbers*, so in order to sensibly use these functions we must use numbers only as their input.

Comment: Related (dupe?) http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7668/ Partially related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13060/

Comment: Another way of seeing clearly why an exponential's argument should be dimensionless is to Taylor expand: $\exp(x) = 1 +x + x^2 /2 + ...$ Every term has a different dimension if $x$ is dimensionful, and hence cannot be summed. See: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/relativity/three.pdf for detailed notes on dimensional analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To consider an example, take the case of exponential decay

$$N=N_\circ e^{-\lambda t}$$

We can write this as

\begin{eqnarray*}
N & = & \frac{N_{\circ}}{e^{\lambda t}}\\
 & = & \frac{N_{\circ}}{\underbrace{e\times e\times e\times e\times\ldots \times e}_{\lambda t\text{ times}}}
\end{eqnarray*}

So $\lambda t$ must be a dimensionless term that is telling how many times we should multiply $e$ by itself. Thus, $\lambda t$ must be dimensionless "overall". Individually, $\lambda$ has the dimensions of $[T^{-1}]$ which cancels with $t$ to give a net dimensionless quantity.

$\underbrace{e\times e\times e\times \ldots}_{10 \text{ meters times}}$ makes no sense mathematically.

We could have taken a dimensional quantity instead of $e$ but the exponent $\lambda t$ would still be dimensionless. eg in the kinematical equation $s=ut + \frac 12 at^2$,  $t^2$ has the dimensions of $[T^2]$ but the exponent $2$ is dimensionless.

The same applies to transcendental functions i.e. logarithmic, trigonometric, etc.

Comment: it is getting impossible for me to bring the alphabets in superscript

Comment: @elle It's mathjax, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1

Comment: In   $e^{\lambda t}$    ‘λt’   is dimensionless,  so we say that   ‘$e^{\lambda t}$ ’ (whole) is dimensionless. 
       
Now  in      $e^{\lambda t}$    ‘λt’ is dimensionless, so would    $e^{\lambda t}$   (whole)  be dimensionless?

Comment: @elle The *exponent* ($\lambda t$) is dimensionless but if the *base* ($e$) is not dimensionless, then as a whole, $e^{\lambda t}$ won't be dimensionless (unless the exponent is zero of course.) Eg $\text {meter}^2$ has the dimensions $[L^2]$. Here, the exponent $2$ is dimensionless.